# Unable to access any of the windows default application or services in Windows 7. Visual Stduios 2013 not able to reset settings as well

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-7, environment-variables, environment

When ever I try to launch any of the windows default services or applications like notepad, environment variables or services or visual studios. I see up this random message: 
"Windows cannot find %windir%\system32\mmc.exe Make sure you types the name corrrectly and then try again. "

How do I fix these weird issues I see when ever I launch any of the windows 7 default applications or services?

Try:
I have tried to restart my computer and even removed or deleted the application settings for visual studios. This foes not fix the problems. I tried to run the devenv.exe /reset settings for visual studios. After every restart the services work fine for sometime and then gets into this unstable state. Can I try anything new or different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reduce the system path in environment variables by manually going to the folder: c:\windows\system32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe and deleting one entry from my PATH to put me under 2048 chars. New cmd windows work just fine.

Make sure your Path is always less than 2048 Characters. So we don't see this error again. I faced this problem once and was able to solve it this way.

Comment: Thanks alot Deepak for the answer. This worked for me and I was able to fix my problem using your suggestions. This helped me alot. You are a saver...:-)

I have too many applications in the Path and just removed some of then and made sure the PATH variable is less than 2048. This Works now..:-)